# How to refresh Test data with Production data Automatically  -- ORACLE

Tags: database, testing, refresh, production

What is the best way to refresh test data with Production data Automatically ? I am using Oracle database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- export the production database using [expdp](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#i1007466)
- drop the contents of the test database
- import the production dump using [impdp](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_import.htm#i1007653)

Comment: I have not used any time expdb and impdb, can the export and import operation will be done automatically every day like a service which runs automatically ?

Comment: Yes that can be scheduled. Either as an operating system job ("cron job") or through Oracle using `dbms_datapump` and `dbms_scheduler`